# Python- categorising numbers

Tags: python

I have a column in a data named availability_365 the column contains numbers between 0 and 365. I want a python code that would categorise the numbers to fall between 1 and 3. So if the number is between 0 and 122 it should be converted to 1, numbers 123-245 should be converted to 2 and 245-365 be converted to 3. Would appreciated any help please, thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to have codes.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include your snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your last condition should be 246-365, otherwise 245 should be replaced by both 2 and 3, and that's impossible. This is a bug in specification.

You need to make three if checks:

```
def convert_365(availability_365: list, a=1, b=2, c=3):
    converted = []
    for number in availability_365:
        if number < 123:
            converted.append(a)
        elif 122 < number <= 245:
            converted.append(b)
        elif number >= 246:
            converted.append(c)
    return converted

#  Making a list from 0 to 365
availability_365 = list(range(0, 366))

print(convert_365(availability_365))

#  Checking the boundaries
print(convert_365(availability_365)[0] == 1)
print(convert_365(availability_365)[122] == 1)
print(convert_365(availability_365)[123] == 2)
print(convert_365(availability_365)[245] == 2)
print(convert_365(availability_365)[246] == 3)
print(convert_365(availability_365)[365] == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is basically rounding. Integer division by the step size almost directly gives the desired result, you just need to shift by 1.

```
def categorise(num):
    return (num // 123) + 1

print(categorise(0))    # 1
print(categorise(122))  # 1
print(categorise(123))  # 2
print(categorise(245))  # 2
print(categorise(246))  # 3
print(categorise(365))  # 3
```